# Does the symfony cache file system handle ext2 32000 files in the same directory limitation?

Tags: php, caching, symfony1, ext2

Does the symfony cache system handle ext2 32000 files in the same directory limitation ?

I have 80000 users and i want to cache their profiles but do symfony cache system handle the ext2 limitation ?

i'm also posting for the others who will face the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure whether my answer is correct but in `PROJECT/lib/symfony/cache/sfCacheFile.class.php` there is a method: [`sfCacheFile::getFilePath()`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/cache/sfFileCache.class.php#L211) that returns a path to a file. It seems that there is no any protection against limitations of `ext2` filesystem.

But there is a very simple solution - override that class:

1. In `PROJECT/apps/APP/config/factories.yml` set your own cache class:

   ```
   default:
   # Others factories (if any)

     view_cache:
       class: myOwnFileCache
       param:
         automatic_cleaning_factor: 0
         cache_dir:                 %SF_TEMPLATE_CACHE_DIR%
         lifetime:                  86400
         prefix:                    %SF_APP_DIR%/template
   ```
2. Now create that class and make sure it extends `sfFileCache` and overrides `getFilePath()`

   ```
   # PROJECT/lib/PROJECT/cache/myOwnFileCache.class.php        
   class myOwnFileCache extends sfFileCache {
       protected getFilePath($key) {
           /*
               Convert from: abcdef
                         to: a/b/abcdef
           */
           $key = substr($key, 0, 1) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($key, 1, 1) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $key;
           return parent::getFilePath($key);
       }
   ```

   }
3. Clear cache: `./symfony cc`

Now you need 32000 cache keys that starts **with the exact same** two letters/digits to crush your filesystem.